# Bluetooth printing via SPP from microcontroller

Tags: printing, bluetooth, microcontroller, printer-control-language, spp

We've got a self-built mobile device which can transfer data via Bluetooth SPP to a PC. On the market there are numerous devices acting as mobile printers via Bluetooth. Some of them use a custom ASCII-based printing language, e.g. the label printers from Zebra.

So there is the idea of printing via SPP from our device.
Sadly there is not too much usable information on the internet on this special topic.

Can you recommend any printer (at least A4) capable of printing via Bluetooth SPP with publicly available protocol specs?
Or do you have any hints where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth printers typically use profiles other than SPP.  There are several flavors, some printers will support a variety of them:

1) BPP - Basic Print Profile can send simple text-based data, no need for printer-specific drivers

2) HCRP - Hard Copy Cable Replacement Profile is used to send the same data format as you would over a wire, typically requires printer-specific drivers to format the data.

3) BIP - Basic Imaging Profile allows transfer of photos, etc.

4) OPP - Object Push Profile is also sometimes used to transfer files

So in general, you are not going to be able to just use SPP to talk to a normal printer, although these other profiles may sit on top of SPP.